# How to send data to POST method from HTML table in View in this scenario?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, viewmodel

I have some data that I am displaying in `HTML` table in my `View`. Now, what I want to do is that upon clicking a button (say a `SUBMIT` button, I want to send the data to the POST method of the Controller so that I can save the data to the database.

I have tried to get the data using `Model Binding` technique, however, the `ViewModel` object in the `POST` Method comes out to be `null`.

**Model and ViewModel**

```
// Model Model.cs    
public class MyModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    ...
}

// ViewModel MyViewModel.cs
public class MyViewModel
{
            public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    ...
    public List<MyModel> MyModelList { get; set; }
}

// ViewModel VMList.cs
public class VMList
{
    public List<MyViewModel> MyViewModelList { get; set; }
}
```

So, I have a `Model` called `MyModel.cs` which has is the table in the database. Then, I have a `ViewModel` called `MyViewModel.cs' that has the same columns as the`Model`, in addition to some columns, plus a`List`of`MyModel`type. Then, there is another`ViewModel`called`VMList.cs`that contains a list of tuples of`MyViewModel`type. This`ViewModel`is passed to the`View`.

The View is constructed in the following manner:

**View**

```
@model ...Models.ViewModels.VMList
...
<form asp-action="MyAction" asp-controller="MyController" id="myForm">
    <div>
        <button type="submit" value="submit" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
        <table id="myTable">
            @foreach(var item in Model.MyViewModelList)
            {
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Header 3</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @item.FirstName
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @item.LastName
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @item.Header3
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @if(item.subList != null && item.subList.Count() != 0)
                    {
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>SubList Header 1</th>
                                <th>SubList Header 2</th>
                                <th>SubList Header 3</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach(var subItem in item.subList)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        @subItem.SubListHeader1
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @subItem.SubListHeader2
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @subItem.SubListHeader3
                                    </td>
                               </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    }
            }
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

**POST Method**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult MyAction(VMList vmListObject)
{
    return View();
}
```

How can I get the data that is shown in the tables in the `View` back to the `Controller`?

Comment: Firstly, to submit any data to controller from your form, you need the input fields. I do not see any input fields in your form. Secondly, your form action is `MyController.MyAction` but in your post method, you have shown the `Index` method.

Comment: I apologize. That was a typo. I have corrected it in the code. It is correct in the actual code as I am getting a call to the POST method upon clicking the Submit button.

Comment: The `MyAction` method still looks incorrect because it is not accepting any parameters, please paste your actual code here.

Comment: Again a silly typo Priyank. I am very sorry. I should have revised the code before posting. However, it is correct in the actual code.

Comment: Now coming back to my first question, you need to have the input fields to submit anything from the form. You can create some hidden fields for each value in `<td>` that you want to submit to the controller. However, to get it correct you have to name it correctly. I would suggest you have a look at editor templates once.

Comment: I will try it out by adding <input></input>.

Comment: @Dashamlav just use `@Html.EditorFor(item => item.PropertyName)` to generate the inputs. it will generate the inputs with the propers names to be serialized and it is the .net way of doing things- leverage what the framework gives you

Comment: Is there any other way apart from using HTML Helpers?

Comment: yes you can hand write the inputs but why would you want to do that? check out how to serialize lists in .net as there are some gotchas involved however as long as rows aren't being added/removed from the table then it is straightforward. i don't see any reason not to use html helpers

Comment: I will check it out. I know about HTMK Helpers, but I want to implement this without using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on models you given,try to use `asp-for` tag helper and `name` property for model binding.

```
@model  VMList
<form asp-action="MyAction" asp-controller="HomeController" id="myForm">
<div>
    <button type="submit" value="submit" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
    <table id="myTable">
        @{ int i = 0;}
        @foreach (var item in Model.MyViewModelList)
        {
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Header 3</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input asp-for="@item.FirstName" name="vmListObject.MyViewModelList[@i].FirstName" />

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input asp-for="@item.LastName" name="vmListObject.MyViewModelList[@i].LastName"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input asp-for="@item.Header3" name="vmListObject.MyViewModelList[@i].Header3" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @if (item.MyModelList != null && item.MyModelList.Count() != 0)
                {
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>SubList Header 1</th>
                            <th>SubList Header 2</th>
                            <th>SubList Header 3</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @{ int j = 0;}
                        @foreach (var subItem in item.MyModelList)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input asp-for="@subItem.FirstName" name="vmListObject.MyViewModelList[@i].MyModelList[@j].FirstName"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input asp-for="@subItem.LastName" name="vmListObject.MyViewModelList[@i].MyModelList[@j].LastName" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    test
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            j++;
                        }

                    </tbody>
                  }
            </tbody>
           i++;
         }
    </table>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Using your suggestion, I was able to get the data over to the `POST` method of Controller, but upon checking, I was getting the inner loop as `null`.

Comment: @Dashamlav I test it without any problem.Make sure the `name` property is set correspond to fields' name of model.